# How do you lock access to a particular function when using multiprocessing library in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Given n number of processes, I would like to allow only the first process to write to a file after waiting some time and the remaining processes should then be able to only read that file.

How would I achieve that with Lock or anything else?
Note: I need to use imap_unordered with partial like its shown below.

```
def read_text_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
    return lines

def write_text_file(filename, text):
    time.sleep(4)
    with open(filename, "w") as fp:
        fp.writelines(text)

def main_fn(i, filename):
    iproc, (hp1, hp2) = i
    res = do_something(iproc+1, hp1, hp2, filename)
    return res

def do_something(iproc, v1, v2, filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        result = f"This is the first process ---> process-{iproc} with {v1} and {v2} \n"
        write_text_file(filename, result)
    else:
        # print(f"Process {iproc} here...{v1}---{v2}")
        text = read_text_file(filename)
        result = f"This is process:{iproc} with {v1} and {v2} and not what you've read: {text} \n"
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Inputs
    filename = r"D:\test_mp.txt"
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
    hparams = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 13)]

    # Create a multiprocess that would spawn each of these process
    pool = mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes=3)
    train_fn = partial(main_fn, filename=filename)

    res_iter = pool.imap_unordered(train_fn, enumerate(hparams))

    # Print results
    for i, res in enumerate(res_iter):
        print(f"Final: {i+1} --> {res}")
```

When I run the above program, I get the following output

```
Final: 1 --> This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 

Final: 2 --> This is process:4 with 4 and 4 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n'] 

Final: 3 --> This is process:5 with 5 and 5 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n'] 

Final: 4 --> This is process:6 with 6 and 6 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n'] 

Final: 5 --> This is process:7 with 7 and 7 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 6 --> This is process:8 with 8 and 8 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 7 --> This is process:9 with 9 and 9 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 8 --> This is process:10 with 10 and 10 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 9 --> This is process:11 with 11 and 11 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 10 --> This is process:12 with 12 and 12 and not what you've read: ['This is the first process ---> process-1 with 1 and 1 \n']

Final: 11 --> This is the first process ---> process-2 with 2 and 2

Final: 12 --> This is the first process ---> process-3 with 3 and 3
```

Ideally I would like to have the lines Final: 11 and Final: 12 ... similar to Final 2...Final9 and not Final:1.

Comment: So use two different functions.  Start 1 of the first and N of the second.  However, there's still a problem here.  There's no guarantee the file will be created by the time a future process tries to read it.  Ordering is not guaranteed.  Perhaps you need to run the writer in your main app, and then start a bunch of subprocesses.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).